# What are the use cases and benefits of withRenderProps?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

Recompose now offers [withRenderProps](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withrenderprops). I understand what it does. What I don't understand is why would I want to use it in my project that already uses recompose's HOCs.

What are the use cases and benefits of using withRenderProps?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc) might be interesting. :)

Comment: Take a look at this post https://hackernoon.com/do-more-with-less-using-render-props-de5bcdfbe74c specially watch the video by Michael Jackson, (No, not the singing one) :wink.

Comment: I understand the render prop pattern. What I'd like to know is *when* to convert recompose's HOCs (or my own HOCs) this way, using withRenderProps.